# Appending an extra request to JSON callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

### My Problem

I am trying to load JSON encoded data from a remote site using jQuery, however when jQuery tries to call this URL it appends the correct function to callback=? so it's something like callback=jsonp1256856769 but it also adds _=1256856769 to the url. So the url ends up being something like http://www.example.com/link/to/file.php?format=json&lang=en&callback=jsonp1256856769&_=1256856769

Now the problem is that that file that I am using that calls it can't interpret the _=1234234 and I can't change it so I have to fix the jQuery problems

### My Question

How can I get jQuery to not appened that _= to the URL that it calls

### What I have done to try to figure out my problem

- Removed all other javascript libraries from the page
- Tried several different versions of jQuery

### My Code

```
function getData(){
    url = "http://www.example.com/link/to/file.php";
    url += "?format=json&lang=en";
    $.getJSON(url+"&callback=?",function(data){formatData(data);});
}
```

*Above is the snippet of JavaScript that I am currently using

*Note the domain I am using is not example.com

Comment: Have you tried specifying `_` in your query string with a valid value?

Comment: I have not, however the problem is not the value of _ but that _ exists. The API I'm pulling is not the greatest and breaks when _ is passed to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** added code

The `_=` part is there, because JSONP request are `cache: false` by default. You can set `cache: true`, which will make the `_=` part go away, but the browser will cache the requests.

```
function getData() {
    url = "http://www.example.com/link/to/file.php";
    url += "?format=json&lang=en";
    $.ajax({
        'url': url,
        'type': 'GET',
        'dataType': 'jsonp', // this adds &callback=? by design
        'cache': true,
        'success': function(data) { formatData(data); }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you still want the caching turned on, but not with the `_=`, then you should add some random property to the request like: `&r=<random value>`

Comment: The content Im pulling won't really change much so it does not matter if it is cached or not